# Protected Async Sub not executed on production

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, async-await

On my local machine this code works when I click the button with ID `lbtnPay`:

```
Protected Sub lbtnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnPay.Click
    ReportError("lbtnPay_Click")
    StartPayment(ddlAmount.SelectedValue * 100)
End Sub

Protected Async Sub StartPayment(ByVal priceInCents As Integer) 'already includes 21% TAX
    ReportError("StartPayment") 

    Dim paymentResponse As PaymentResponse = Await paymentClient.CreatePaymentAsync(paymentRequest)

End Sub

<asp:Panel ID="pnlWallet" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnPay" Text="<%$Resources:paynow %>" runat="server"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

However, when I place this code on my production server and click the `lbtnPay` button, the page just keeps loading and the codeline `ReportError("StartPayment")` is never executed. This codeline is `ReportError("lbtnPay_Click")`

I Googled and searched SO but I find nothing that could even point me in the direction of where I should look.
What settings that may differ between my local dev environment and prod server could potentially impacts correct working of Async functions?

Comment: How come you are not awaiting anything? For example: `Await StartPayment()`... If you do this then `lbtnPay_Click` needs to be `Async`. Also if `ReportError` doesn't need to be awaited then remove the `Async` keyword as you are not awaiting anything.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Good call, I left that out to keep it legible. I've now added the Await codeline in StartPayment. This justifies the current code, correct? So I guess my question is still why it works locally but not on production.

Comment: Current code looks fine as far as I can tell. I don't really have a good answer as to why it works locally and not on your production environment. One thing for sure is if you don't await an async method there's really no guarantee that the code will even complete. It's also like saying `Task.Run` it's not awaited so there's no guarantee it will complete.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ thanks. So you're saying you recommend changing `StartPayment` to `Await StartPayment` to be sure?

Comment: Anything that is `Async` should also be awaited IMHO... So yes, `Await StartPayment`.

Comment: Ok, maybe a dumb follow-up question then, but I would then change my code to: `Protected Async Sub lbtnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnPay.Click
        Await StartPayment(ddlAmount.SelectedValue * 100)
    End Sub`
 Which would mean I now also need to call `lbtnPay_Click` as `Await` (which is not possible since it's a HTML button)?

Comment: Just mark `lbtnPay_Click` as `Async` that's it.

Comment: This is not true. A Task could / should be awaited. `Async` keyword on a method allows you to `Await` inside it. Your event handler `lbtnPay_Click` could be `Async` (and the handler itself is still not awaited, see?) and allow you to `Await StartPayment...` inside it. But Start Payment will need to return a Task. Or you could just create a task on the fly `Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() StartPayment(ddlAmount.SelectedValue * 100))`. You need to make your own Action because StartNew doesn't accept a method with an argument. But the line I provided should work.

Comment: Also your asp needs to be marked Async: `<%@ Page Language="VB" Async="true" ... %>`

Comment: @djv good insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ASP.NET Web Forms you have to register asynchronous code as a Page Task:

```
Protected Sub lbtnPay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnPay.Click

    ReportError("lbtnPay_Click")

    RegisterAsyncTask(AddressOf StartPaymentAsync)

End Sub

Protected Async Function StartPaymentAsync() As Task

    Dim priceInCents = ddlAmount.SelectedValue * 100

    ReportError("StartPayment") 

    Dim paymentResponse As PaymentResponse = Await paymentClient.CreatePaymentAsync(paymentRequest)

End Sub
```

Check this article out:

[Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET 4.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45)